# Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision

Tags: node.js, react-native

I got this error:

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: PickerAndroid
Paths: /Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/differ/matricesDiffer.js collides with /Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/differ/pointsDiffer.js

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name accross two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: PickerAndroid
Paths: /Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/differ/matricesDiffer.js collides with /Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/differ/pointsDiffer.js

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name accross two different files.
at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:162:15)
at /Users/David/Documents/mobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:127:25
```

I tried rm -rf node_modules && npm install, watchman watch-del-all, react-native start -- --reset-all... didnt help

Comment: I think this is caused by incompatible package with your version of react-native.

Comment: @AakashSigdel but the package is in react-native... do I need to updat it? it worked 10minutes ago and now it isn't? so weird

Comment: that is weird. did you do anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: not knowingly... man this sucks.. no idea what to do

Comment: By the looks of it, the problem is from PickerAndroid, you could may be remove the package, and comment out the use of it, and see if it works.

Comment: how do I remove a package that's inside react-native? it's part of utilities and never explicitly declarated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123134/discussion-between-dv3-and-aakash-sigdel).